# Cordova fails to build but PATH, ANT_HOME & JAVA_HOME is set correctly

Tags: cordova

I am trying to build Cordova but I get the following error code:

```
C:\Users\JapSeyz\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 2

Total time: 5 seconds

D:\Lager\Diverse\Cordorva\hello\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\Lager\Diverse\Cordorva\hello\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: D:\Lager\Diverse\Cordorva\hello\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

ANT version is 1.9.4

JDK version is 1.7.0_71

I am just trying to run the standard generated app.

Comment: What does your java_home point to ? JRE or JDK ?

Comment: JDK.

It seems that removing some plugins that were not "official" com.apache solved the issue.